# How to draw a line from two points?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I draw a line from 2 circles using System.Draw in an Windows Form Application?

Comment: Please start by posting what you have tried already, following the guide of posting [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Graphics.DrawLine, for example:

```
public void DrawLinePoint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Create pen.
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    // Create points that define line.   
    Point point1 = new Point(100, 100);   
    Point point2 = new Point(500, 100);   

    // Draw line to screen.   
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, point1, point2);   
}
```

See MSDN for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f956fzw1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `Graphics.DrawLine()` method.

Have a look at the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f956fzw1(v=vs.110).aspx).